# Best method to handle multiple client connections under Windows (without the usage of threads)?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, visual-c++

I find creating a thread for each client connection costly, also there is a limit to the number of threads I can create, and so a limit to the number of connections. What other options do I have? I have read that `select()` can be used but I need to do some tweaking to allow for a large number of connections.

Note that I do not want to use an external library.

Comment: what's the problem with `select`? how many simultaneous connections do you have?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath I have hundreds of simultaneous  connections, but each connection have many sockets, so I have thousands of sockets (I would say that I have 5000 sockets max).

Comment: From my experience, the worst thing to do is to rule out possible solutions right in the start. You say "No threads" and you say "Not one connection per thread". While the latter is clearly a good idea, the former will not allow you to find a good solution. Network programming is the art to really understand the requirements of your application and find the best approach to do it. If in doubt, build multiple solutions and test, prototype and benchmark.

Comment: @user2225104 I am 100% sure that I would not use threads.

Comment: It all depends on the type of your communication. Do you need high through put or low latency? Do you have sporadic traffic spikes...how long will a connection last? High frequency connects/disconnect? Long lasting connections? Just setting all sockets to nonblocking and looping will only get you so far.

Comment: How about I/O Completion Ports?

Comment: @PaulRooney They typically use thread pools. He said "no threads" ;)

Comment: On a side note. I recently was playing with Windows fibers. You can build great co-routine style of single threaded multi fiber applications with it. But it has its own downsides. Did anyone ever use fibers for communications? I wonder how viable that approach might be.

Comment: @user2225104 Actually they specify that there is a limit to the number of threads they can create so a thread pool ma be perfectly fine.

Comment: @user2225104: I think what he meant is that he doesn't want a thread PER connection (which is usually a good idea...)

Comment: @Karoly Horvath Yes this is what I meant. And no one thread per connection is not a good idea in this case (I'm not sure if it is technically possible to create 5000 threads!).

Comment: @Karoly Horvath What about select(), can it handle 5000 sockets?

Comment: Maybe `libev` event based. Yes it's a library but where else could we go?

Comment: I would not use libev on windows and take the extra costs and limitations of a library trying to simulate epoll. For 5000 connections, I am pretty sure completion ports are indeed the way to go.

Comment: @user2225104 Thanks, I will have a look at completion ports, so I should not use select()?

Comment: This is the story behind select on unix like systems. At one point they found out that having an array with (say... ) 5000 entries and migrating it from user to kernel space anytime something happens is not really scaling. On FreeBsd they created k-queue as a better scaling alternative, keeping the state on kernel side. On linux they did e-poll which is similar to k-queue in some aspects, not in others. So select is typically not the way to go if you hare really many connections to maintain.

Comment: @user2225104 Yes I read about its problems on Linux, but I was talking about Windows.

Comment: Select is only there on windows because they wanted to provide socket api and select is kind of part of that. I do not think high end solutions ever use this.

Comment: @user2225104 So I guess that the only way to go if I only care about large number of simultaneous connections, and not really caring about latency or stuff like that is either to use thread pool, or IO completion ports. Am I right?

Comment: IO completion ports go together with thread pools, usually.

Comment: @user2225104 is IOCP used with blocking or non blocking sockets?

Comment: He didn't say "no threads" (hard to write any code that executes with zero threads involved) he said he didn't want a thread per connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use I\O Completion Ports these allow you to scale to 100's of thousands of connections using a small number of threads.

If cross platform is NOT your goal then it's best to write directly to the Windows IOCP API rather than using any of the cross platform libraries.

Note that I have [some articles and some code you can download here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html) explains how to use IOCP.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the asio library - available standalone or as part of boost

Here is a link to the example page - you will see a single-threaded http server. extremely simple, very lightweight, no linking to other libraries necessary.

http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.11.0/doc/asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html#asio.examples.cpp11_examples.http_server

Comment: You should probably elaborate a bit for this to fully qualify as an answer, preferably with an example.

Comment: The "look at asio library" is kind of a standard reply to many questions. My return question is: Would you rather tackle a task with a huge toolbox and tools to choose from or with a swiss army knife? Asio is good to get something done, not really caring about all the little details to obtain an optimized solution.

Comment: apologies. I'm on a mobile. will elaborate later

Comment: OP said: "Note that I do not want to use an external library."

Comment: The asio library is not a huge toolbox. It is a template-only library that specifically solves this problem perfectly. There is plenty of documentation in the library for single, multi and stackless servers.